# cheerio webcrawler get sequence element

Tags: node.js, web-crawler, cheerio

i'm developing a web crawler to read a html code like this:

```
<h3>title 1</h3>
<p>content 1</p>
<h3>title 2</h3>
<p>content 2</p>
<h3>title 3</h3>
<p>content 3</p>
<h3>title 4</h3>
<p>content 4</p>
<h3>title 5</h3>
<p>content 5</p>
```

i want to match title 1 with content 1, title 2 with content 2 and go on. I didn't find in cheerio documentation or jquery a way to get next element or loop all the DOM.

in the docs, i only can go inside a element (children) and come back (parents). but i can't find a way to get the next '

' after find the '' above it.

any ideia ?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple ways:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const $ = cheerio.load('<h3>title 1</h3><p>content 1</p><h3>title 2</h3><p>content 2</p><h3>title 3</h3><p>content 3</p><h3>title 4</h3><p>content 4</p><h3>title 5</h3><p>content 5</p>')

$('h3').get().map( h3 => {
  let title = $(h3).text()
  let content = $(h3).next().text()
  // or
  content = $(h3.nextSibling).text()
  console.log(title, content)
} )
```

jQuery lets you do `$(h3).find('+ p')` which would be nice but cheerio doesn't support it.